# Trying to count the number of times a letter appears using only a while loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to count how many o's there are in the raw input 'phrase' and it counts the first o and says it's done however there are many o's after that. How do I get it to count all of the o's with no for loop.

```
while loop_count<len(phrase):
    if "o" in phrase:
        loop_count += 1
        count2 += 1
      if loop_count>len(phrase):
          print loop_count
          break
      else:
          continue
  else:
    print loop_count
    continue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets try to dissect your code you understand what is going on. See my comments

```
while loop_count<len(phrase):
    if "o" in phrase: # See comment 1
        loop_count += 1 # Why are you incrementing both of these?
        count2 += 1
      if loop_count>len(phrase): # What is this statement for? It should never happen.
                ## A loop always exits once the condition at the while line is false
                ## It seems like you are manually trying to control your loop
                ##  Which you dont need to do
          print loop_count
          break # What does this accomplish?
      else:
          continue
  else:
    print loop_count
    continue # Pointless as we are already at end of loop. Consider removing
```

**Comment 1:** You are asking if an 'o' is anywhere in the phrase. You instead want to ask if the current letter is an o. Perhaps you ment to access a LETTER of the phrase with the index, such as `if 'o' == phrase[loop_count]`. If you do this you want to increment loop_count every time, but the o count only when the letter is an o.

You could re-write it like this:

```
loop_count, o_count = 0, 0
while loop_count<len(phrase):
    # loop_count represents how many times we have looped so far
    if "o" == phrase[loop_count].lower(): # We ask if the current letter is 'o'
        o_count += 1 # If it is an 'o', increment count
    loop_count += 1 # Increment this every time, it tracks our loop count

print o_count
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [sum](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) with an iterator (in this case a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression)):

```
>>> sum(c=='o' for c in 'oompa loompa')
4
```

You can use a regex with len:

```
>>> re.findall('o', 'oompa loompa')
['o', 'o', 'o', 'o']
>>> len(re.findall('o', 'oompa loompa'))
4
```

You could use a Counter:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter('oompa loompa')['o']
4
```

Or just use the 'count' method of the string:

```
>>> 'oompa loompa'.count('o')
4
```

If you really *want* to use a while loop, use a list as a stack with the pop method:

```
s='oompa loompa'
tgt=list(s)
count=0
while tgt:
    if tgt.pop()=='o':
        count+=1
```

Or a 'for' loop -- more Pythonic:

```
count=0        
for c in s:
    if c=='o':
        count+=1
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `count` function :

```
phrase.count('o')
```

but if you want to send a message after one match of 'o' for skip loop over the all of string just use 'in' look like this:

```
if 'o' in phrase :
 # show your message ex: print('this is false')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using comprehensions

```
len([i for i in phrase if i=="o"])
```